# Button> random image> if new image-special>remove previous in paragraph2 and show image in p2> else -remove prev images in p1 show new image in p1

Tags: javascript, image, random, filter, removechild

The title might sound a bit confusing since I tried to make it as short and simple as possible but this is hard to do since the problem is not that simple. I am currently making a website using notepad++ so i am using javascript css and php.

I want when i press a button, a random number generator picks a number that hasn't been picked before, lets say between 0-10. then it returns image['the random number'] where image[] is my array of images, and displays it in paragraph 1(p1). if i click again, it is going to remove the previous image and put a new one. I have done that.

Now i want to have special images, for example image[3] and image[4] so when the random generator picks 3 or 4, i want it the image to be displayed next to the other images.

Lets simulate a scenario,
image[1](not special) is shown. Then image 2(not special) is shown and image 1 is removed. then Image 3(special) is shown next to image 2 without removing it. But then image 5(not special) is shown and it removes image 2(and doesnt remove image3 which is a special image). And if image4(special) is picked, then image 3(special) is removed, the new image5(which wasnt special) stays, and image 4 is displayed next to it. And if it keeps going, it just replaces the non special images with not special ones, and the special ones with only special ones.

Here is my code:

the css part (nothing important, its for styling the button)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />


<style>  
body{
background-image: url("pic3.jpg")
}
  .button1{
position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 80%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  background: white;    
  color: #f56c42;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  }
</style>

</head>
```

the php part (initialzing the button and pic 1, which is shown in the beginning and when you press next card its replaced with one of the images in the array images[]

```
<body>

<h1> <img src="pic4.png" alt="pic4" style="margin: 0px 375px;"> </h1>
<p id="p1" style="text-align: center; border:8px;border-style:solid;padding:2em;border-color:#fc6e00;" > 

<img src= "pic1.jpg" alt="pic1" id="pic1" style="margin: 0px 200px; width:850px;height:450px;">

<button id="button3" onclick="f1();" class="button1">Next Card</button>

<img src= "pic2.jpg" alt="pic2" id="pic2" 
 style="display:none; margin: 0px 200px; width:850px;height:450px;" >

</p>
<p id="p2" style="text-align: center; border:8px;border-style:solid;padding:2em;border-color:white;color: white" > </p>
```

the javascript part:

```
<script>

var g=0;   //counter how many times the function has been called
var arr=[];  //empty array i fill with the random numbers so i can remove repeated ones


    function f1() 
    {


      var theImages = [{    //array with the images
            src: "img1.png",
            width: "500",
            height: "700",
        }, {
            src: "img2.png",
           width: "500",
            height: "700",

        }, {
            src: "img3.png",
          width: "500",
            height: "700",
        }, {
            src: "img4.png",
          width: "500",
            height: "700",
        },
 {
            src: "img5.png",
          width: "500",
            height: "700",
        }, {
            src: "img6.png",
          width: "500",
            height: "700",
        }, {
            src: "img7.png",
          width: "500",
            height: "700",
        }, {
            src: "img8.png",
          width: "500",
            height: "700",
        }];

        var endCard=[{    

<!-- array for the end card, 
i know this is not needed but this is how it worked so 
i saved some headaches for me -->
            src: "img0.png",
            width: "500",
            height: "700",
        }];
        var endcardbuffer= [];  

<!--end card buffer ( im not sure i need a buffer but 
it works so i dont touch it, i had some problems that said 
"not an object" so with this i dont have that -->
            endcardbuffer[0] = new Image();
            endcardbuffer[0].src = endCard[0].src;
            endcardbuffer[0].width = endCard[0].width;
            endcardbuffer[0].height = endCard[0].height;

        var i;
        var preBuffer = [];
        for (i = 0;i< theImages.length;i++) { //sets up the images in preBuffer

            preBuffer[i] = new Image();
            preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i].src;
            preBuffer[i].width = theImages[i].width;
            preBuffer[i].height = theImages[i].height;
        }

    function getRandomInt() {   //returns an image(preBuffer['random num'] or the endcard
        g++;   //everything except the imn=math... line is for the removal of repeated numbers
      var j=0;
      var a;
       while(j>=0)  
      {
           imn = Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 - preBuffer.length )) + preBuffer.length;
           a = imn; 
            arr[g-1]=a; 
            j=0;
           for(i=0;i<theImages.length;i++)
           { 
             if(arr[i] === a)   
                  {j++;}       
           }
         if(g>theImages.length)    
        {  return endcardbuffer[0];   }        

      if(j<2)         
       break;
    }

        return preBuffer[imn];
        }

var newImage=getRandomInt();

var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var l = images.length;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { // remove the previous images
    images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
}

document.getElementById("p1").appendChild(newImage);  // display the image 
}

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my code. right now, it shows up to 8 images, when the last image is shown every time you press the button it will give you the endcard.

what i have tried: in getRandomInt() i added this line

```
if (a==3 || a==4)
    {
    return 0;
    }
```

which will return me 0 if its a special number

all of this below is added after the getRandomInt() {} function

```
var x=getRandomInt();
var newImage;   


if(x==0){
if(g%2==0)         

<!-- this is not perfect and i want to have more than 2 special images,
 with this approach i can only have 2 (when my counter is even and when its odd),
 i can figure this out but i dont know how to not remove the old image,
 which is my problem so if it works with 2 i will figure out how to work with more) -->

 {newImage = preBuffer[3];}
else{newImage=preBuffer[4];}
 var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var l = images.length;

document.getElementById("p2").appendChild(newImage);  // display the image 
}

else{
newImage=x;
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var l = images.length;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { // remove the previous images
    images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
}

document.getElementById("p1").appendChild(newImage);  // display the image 
}
}
```

the problem i believe is with the appendChild. I am removing the special images as well when i press the button. i have tried a few other versions changing some stuff but most of them said "not an object " when it returned the special image.

I would be glad if someone can help. Regards!

Comment: Use 2 arrays. One with the images. One with the special ones. On random pick, check if it exists in the special array. If it does, it's special. Otherwise it's not. As for your containers, no need to append. Just have an `<img>` element in there and use JS to change the `src` attribute values to change the image.

Comment: Hi there. I am still a learner so I might not have understood you correctly but anyway, adding a second array is what I first tried but didn't work for me and I have an idea how to do it with 1 array for example the special images take the last 2 places of the array and if the returned number is one of the last two then it's special. And also, I don't know another way to show/remove except for append. I searched for how to do it and append is what popped out. I am not sure I understand how it works as well but the code works. Problem isn't with filtering special images it's with the display.

Comment: I made an example script for you here: [https://jsfiddle.net/hp7q8dg1/](https://jsfiddle.net/hp7q8dg1/) It's really not that difficult :)

Comment: Also, just so you understand the reasoning behind it: `appendChild()` means "Add this to the existing content of". It does not mean "Replace the content of". That's why it's causing you issues and why you shouldn't use that.

Comment: thanks a lot for the work! But anyway, it still doesn't like it when i put the array with the images. I also added the thing i used in my code the thing with prebuffer and still doesn't like the pictures too much. Anyway, I am still trying to work it out so I will make an update when if i finish it.